# Is there a symbol for "dependent"?

Tags: probability, notation

For random variables $A$ and $B$, $A \perp B$ is sometimes used to denote "A is independent of B".  Is there a symbol that is commonly used to mean "A is not independent of B"?

Comment: Perhaps $A \not \perp B$?

Comment: Does $A\top B$ denote anything?

Comment: $y=f(x)$ reads as "$y$ depends on $x$"

Comment: @user2345215 if $\perp$ represents something like "orthogonal" then $\top$ hardly suggests "not orthogonal"

Comment: @janmarqz I would read $A=f(B)$ as $A$ is determined by $B$ rather than information about $B$ affect knowledge about $A$

Comment: No, because AFAIK it is a useless assumption. There's no non-trivial theorems of the form: "If $X$ and $Y$ are dependent random variables, then..." We tend to only name things that are useful as premises.

Comment: @capybaralet there is a wrong spelling in "A in(is) independent of B". It can't be given as an edit because it is less than 6 chars.

Answer (score 10):

From: Wasserman, L. (2013). All of Statistics: A Concise Course in Statistical Inference, Springer.

Wasserman uses a coil symbol. I have not found the Latex symbol, yet.

[From List of Symbols](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oTtGI.png)

Comment: And, with all due respect to the author, this is not a good idea.

Comment: Why is this downvoted? This is an accurate example of a text using a symbol for dependence, exactly what the questioner wanted! Came here because I'm reading it and looking for the latex.

Comment: Bad idea. my EE expertise say to me this is an inductor. 
But I like the book so +1.

Comment: @WeiChing林煒清 it's very common for symbols to have multiple meanings, depending on the context. You EE is only correct if the context is physics.

Answer (score 8):

Independence is denoted $\perp \!\!\! \perp$ not orthogonal $\perp $.
Use "\perp \ ! \ !\ ! \perp" in Tex (remove space between \ and !).
A and B will be assumed to be not independent unless shown otherwise, but I know of no symbol for it.

Comment: Yes, I didn't find $\large\perp\!\!\!\!\!\perp$ in The [Big Table](http://www.rpi.edu/dept/arc/training/latex/LaTeX_symbols.pdf)

Comment: Slashed symbols are here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/26523/whats-the-most-elegant-way-to-obtain-dirac-operators-slash-notation

Comment: "Independence is denoted ⊥⊥ not orthogonal ⊥" - As a counterpoint to this very definitive statement, I would just like to add that this is clearly field-dependent. Basically all of the literature I'm reading in ML / statistics uses the single symbol. (E.g., Hastie/Tibshirani/Friedman's "Elements of statistical learning", Koller/Friedman's "Probabilistic Graphical Models", Murphiy's "Machine Learning - A Probabilistic Perspective", essentially all of the literature on domain adaptation and algorithmic fairness.)

Answer (score 3):

It seems that a crossed ⫫ would do it. In latex code \nBigCI or Unicode U+2aeb. 
Check its use at this nice lecture on causality https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bHOGP5o3Vu0&t=2941s